# best way to implement location.path in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As I know, this is to visit a route and pass param to the url

```
$location.path('/home').search({key:'value'})
```

This is to clear every param and url and visit the route, history is keep

```
$location.search('').path('/home');
```

How about don't keep the history? Like transactional flow, once the user paid, you don't want to let the user to be able to go back. I know there's history service but I think there's more simpler way to do it. I tried to use valina javascript redirect method but it reloaded the entire page which is inconsisten for my SPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call

```
$location.search('').path('/home').replace();
```

and it will not create an extra record in the back-history of the browser.

See documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location).

Comment: with an extra .replace()?